# How to embed a neo4j graph in another site?

Tags: web-applications, neo4j, data-visualization, graph-databases

**Background**

I've been using neo4j to query a fairly large (but ultimately uncomplicated) dataset. I'm writing cypher directly into the web interface and keeping a track of my queries in a text file (old-skool).

**Problem**

I love the results I'm getting back, so I'd like to take this another step and build a more rigorous interface around it so that I can give it to non-technical people to explore the data within some pre-programmed parameters.

I've read the node4j API reference and I'm certain I could build an interface from scratch with a combination of D3 for layout and a back-end middleware app using (for example) seraph in node.js or the neo4j rubygem.

However, the standard neo4j web interface is so good that I wonder if I could leverage it a bit further and embed the query results (including force-directed graphs) in my app, rather than start from scratch?

**Possible approach**

Is there any precedence for this approach? I guess the journey would be something like:

- Construct a query in my 3rd party app
- Query neo4j server
- Receive iframe (or other?) response
- Embed response in 3rd party page

Any advice on this would be ace.

Answer (score 7):

Check out http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization

It explains how to do it yourself but also links to other tools and frameworks that you can use for that.

You can also check out http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo for one example I created a while ago.

Usually most javascript graph visualization frameworks are easy to use.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/developer/tools-graph-visualization/ is the current link

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Neo4j GraphGists](http://gist.neo4j.org/), which was created for the same purpose.

[EDITED]

If you want to access your own database with GraphGists, that seems to be possible. Caveat: I have not tried this myself.

- GraphGist is [available as open source](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist), and you can run it locally on your own computer/server.
- Looking in the GraphGist [installation script](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist/blob/gh-pages/install-graphgist.sh), you can see that it clones another neo4j open source project, called [rabbithole](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole).
- Rabbithole's Readme states that you can configure it to "expose" a local DB:

  > Potential arguments for local execution:
  >
  > ```
  > java org.neo4j.community.console.Console port /path/to/db [expose]
  > ```
  >
  > ("expose" will write and read-through to the graph-db otherwise it
  >   will copy the graph content into an in-memory db)
- Near the bottom of rabbithole's [pom file](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole/blob/master/pom.xml), you can configure rabbithole:

  ```
              <mainClass>org.neo4j.community.console.Console</mainClass>
              <!--arguments>
                <argument>argument1</argument>
              </arguments-->
  ```

  - Theoretically, if you replace `argument1` with `port /path/to/db expose` (and uncomment the `arguments` tag), you will be using your own local DB.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like GraphGists are designed for small datasets that are created on the fly in the browser? My use-case is different – I'd like to query a much larger database sitting on a private server.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide some clues as to how to use your own DB with your own locally hosted GraphGist installation.

Comment: rabbithole doesn't take arguments, https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole/issues/78 (contains patch that needs to be applied)